# Draw Rectangle View with curve bottom In Android

Tags: android, canvas, view, draw, cube

Good day.I want to draw an rectangle as a view but which bottom shall be curved.I do not want to apply background image like that or use any views,because if i use an view and set background,the curve part will still have invisible empty space and i would not be able to attach another curve image to the bottom curve of the custom view.So how shall i draw an rectangle with bottom curved line and use it as a view to set any background color i want?

Notice: i have heard something and read about `quadTo()` and  `cubicTo()` android methods but i have no clue even how to use them i mean i did not understand anything from documents....So i came here for help.

Ideally instead of such description you could see what i really want to achieve from the image...It is an toolbar or action bar or whatsover but i have to make such thing...I have no ideas at all.(By the way you can notice that there is an image curved on top as well...i have to do it too,and i reckon i can do it by drawing an bitmap.meanwhile i'm still failing to do any of the image parts in android view.)[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just play with the oval item values to get the desired output.

curve_toolbar_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"/>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-100dp"
        android:right="-100dp"
        android:top="-80dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/curve_toolbar_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Curve shape toolbar]

Comment: `android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"` or `android:background="@drawable/curve_toolbar_bg"` ?

Comment: @HasanAbdullah Thanks for pointing out, I have updated the original thread..it should be curve_toolbar_bg.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to achieve curved status bar on my android application. This created a toolbar that can be over other views so when you scroll views goes under the toolbar.

First I hid the original Toolbar from activity by creating a no title theme and selecting that theme from manifest. Then I created a Titlebar of my own and then by playing with margins and paddings I achieved desired result.

[statusbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hc3Z.png)

sytles.xml:

```
    <style name="Notitle.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

arch.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"/>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="-100dp"
    android:right="-100dp"
    android:top="-80dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#2629fb"
            android:endColor= "#2699FB"
            android:angle="90" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

mainActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#27292c">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/arch">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerWidgetTitle"
        android:text="Title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollLinearLayout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

            <!-- Your Views -->
      
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```